# Storing and Converting MaterialColors

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter

If I have a MaterialColor (such as Colors.red) and wanted to save it in Firestore (or any database) and then when I restart the app, retrieve and convert that color to a MaterialColor, what would be the best way to do it?

I originally thought of just storing the colors as strings in the database such as "blue", "red", etc and then just use a switch statement to convert them to MaterialColors again. It seems like there is a better way out there. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing the colors as 1,2,3,4… (the smaller better for quick retrieval).

Then in a global class, have a get function that returns the color based on the integer.